# how to convert IEnumerable<JToken> to JArray

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm using LINQ over a `JArray` to filter out the items based on a particular condition and want that result in a separate `JArray`.

```
JArray arrSameClass = (JArray) arrPupilEmailDetails.Where(joSameClass => joSameClass["uClassId"].ToString() == gidClassId.ToString());
```

But this is giving me an casting exception(`'unable to cast from IEnumerable<JToken> to JArray'`). I've tried `JArray.Parse()` also. Any help ?

Comment: how about `where(...).ToArray()`?

Comment: @LeiYang I'm not sure whether it will convert to C# Array or JArray.

Comment: what is `JArray`?

Comment: @LeiYang its a JSON.NET specific class for manipulating Array of JSON

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`JArray(Object)` constructor](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_2.htm) and pass it your `IEnumerable<JToken>` and the enumerable will be evaluated and used to construct the `JArray`:

```
var query = arrPupilEmailDetails.Where(joSameClass => joSameClass["uClassId"].ToString() == gidClassId.ToString());
var arrSameClass = new JArray(query);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WF2eIt).

Comment: Perfect! I have one question though, Is it a good way to pass an IEnumerable as a constructor param? I mean from performance perspective.

Comment: @izengod - At some point a `JArray` constructor is going to need to get called and items are going to need to get added.  This does just that, so it's not prima facie nonperformant.  Beyond that see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Problem I have with this solution is that if array is a child of a bigger object then creating a new `JArray` lose all the `Path` information.

Comment: The issue with that (preserving path) is that if you want to make the result of the query a JArray you have no choice but to change the parent to the new JArray. If you need the original path information then you must process as the original IEnumerable<JToken>.